# Реализация пешеходного маршрута YandexMapKit

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как построить пешеходный маршрут между двумя точками, используя YandexMapKit в своем приложении Android.

Comment: А пробовали посмотреть документацию и демо: https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo. Там есть маршруты прямо с примерами

Comment: Пример этот видел. Обычный маршрут удалось построить. Нужен именно пешеходный

Comment: Для построения пешеходных маршрутов нужно использовать вот этот роутер - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/transport/masstransit/PedestrianRouter.html

Вот тут можно пример посмотреть, только роутер нужно заменить - https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/MasstransitRoutingActivity.java

Comment: Спасибо! Начал уже использовать PedestrianRouter, но не могу его проинициализировать. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Нашел! pedestrianRouter = TransportFactory.getInstance().createPedestrianRouter()